# IE11 + Edge 12-13-14: random JavaScript parsing errors, caused by very long object?

Tags: javascript, parsing, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I'm getting reports of JavaScript errors in production (from TrackJS.com) from IE & Edge browsers like:

- Expected identifier, string or number
- Unterminated string constant
- Expected ': ', '}' or ';'
- illegal character

And when I check the error file / line, it's sometimes in "mathiasbynens/he" library (look on GitHub), like here: [example 1](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/310134/24353407/b3d0ba6e-12ed-11e7-92f4-19e13bf4cfa4.png)

And sometimes it's in other parts of the code (like in YUI library). I've got lots of these and they seem completely random (targeting what seems to be valid code): [example 2](https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/310134/24353434/cd9d8422-12ed-11e7-9061-20c2198f5ede.png)

The only idea I have would be that IE croaks when loading the very long JSON defined in the .js.
Have you ever had any issue of this kind?

Comment: i see no github, just some pics. please add the parts (code and erors) in text form to the question.

Comment: recently I had a question where I had to parse a 24MB JSON string. Edge had no problems with that. did you actually check the charCodes around these positions? Characters are not always what they seem.

Comment: My low reputation prevents me using images or many links, so I'm limited... I've had two ideas : 1) he.js and its very long JSON / lines. 2) YUI minified. I've tried removing he.js and used non-minified files for YUI, and the issue still persists. Here's two examples and the exact code I use (links point to the line the error was reported from) : https://gist.github.com/gnutix/42435d04fc672fe13628cae7babb1988#file-home-js-L7795 and https://gist.github.com/gnutix/42435d04fc672fe13628cae7babb1988#file-home-js-L11914

Comment: I'm still having this issue and have no idea how to find a solution for it... :(

Comment: @gnutix Did you ever find the reason behind or a fix for this?